# Are the effects of hand-optimization of code consistent across different gcc optimization levels?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

If I run gcc with `-O0`, and hand-optimize my code using techniques such as the ones mentioned [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6154/Writing-Efficient-C-and-C-Code-Optimization), will it generally be the case that my optimized code will run faster than my unoptimized code when I run gcc with `-O3`?

That is, if I hand-optimize code under a particular compiler optimization level, is it generally true that these optimizations will still be productive (rather than counterproductive) under a different (higher or lower) compiler optimization level?

Comment: Not necessarily. The compiler understands simple code well and can optimise it well. Complicated hand-optimised code isn't understood as well by the compiler, so often it can't optimise that as well as simple code. But it knows a few common idioms and can handle those without problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be same in different compiler. Even the compiler can do away with your hand optimization, i mean ignore them. It heavily depends the implementation and behavior of the compiler itself. Most of the optimizations are like a request to compiler, which can be dropped at any time, (mostly without any notification)

Comment: Suppose I am using the same compiler version, just with different flags though?

Comment: Sorry, my answer seems a little off. I talked about different compilers. Generally if it is a attribute declaration or similar to that which comes as a separate `tag`, compiler tries to keep that intact as an user constraint till the end. So those case, it might force the compiler to drop a native(inbuilt) optimization. But modification which are like code flow change, using different operators are not treated differently. So these might give way to native optimization. Thus you might get a mixed result depending upon the input. But such conflicting cases should be rare.